# Showing that $g$ is 1-1 given $f$ onto and $gf$ 1-1?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow C$ be functions.

If $f$ is onto and $gf$ is one-to-one, prove $g$ is one-to-one.

I want to know if the reasons why I stated my statements are legitimate - hence, I have written under each statement why I have included it and I'm looking for verification.

> Let $\forall n: y_n \in B$. Assume $g(y_0) = g(y_1)$.

We have to assume $g(y_0) = g(y_1)$ in order to prove $y_0 = y_1$.

> Since $gf$ is 1-1, $\forall (y_n) : g(y_0) = g(y_1) \Longrightarrow f^{-1}(y_0) = f^{-1}(y_1)$.

I show here that there is a one-to-one function from $A$ to $C$. But I have to prove such an inverse exists.

> Since $f$ is onto, $\forall y_n [\exists x_n = f^{-1}(y_n) : f(x_n) = y_n]$.

I prove here the inverse exists by restating a claim.

> Since $f^{-1}(y_0) =f^{-1}(y_1) \Longrightarrow y_0 = y_1$, $g$ is 1-1.

This is true by the definition of function.

Question: Suppose I didn't know $f$ is onto. Does the claim still hold, or does it fail since it is not known that an inverse exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(y_1) = g(y_2)$. Since $f$ is onto we have $y_1 = f(x_1)$ and $y_2 = f(x_2)$. Hence
$$g(f(x_1)) = g(f(x_2)) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_1 = x_2 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y_1 = y_2.$$

If $f$ is not onto, then the claim doesn't hold. For instance, if $A$ contains only one element and $g$ is a constant function then $gf$ is one-to-one.